# Internal Variable PIPESTATUS

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am new to linux and bash scripting and i have query about this internal variable PIPESTATUS which is an array and stores the exit status of individual commands in pipe.

On command line:

```
 $  find /home | /bin/pax -dwx ustar | /bin/gzip -c > myfile.tar.gz
 $ echo ${PIPESTATUS[*]}
 $ 0 0 0
```

working fine on command line but when I am putting this code in a bash script it is showing only one exit status. My default SHELL on command line is bash only.

Somebody please help me to understand why this behaviour is changing? And what should I do to get this work in script?

```
#!/bin/bash

cmdfile=/var/tmp/cmd$$
backfile=/var/tmp/backup$$

find_fun() {
    find /home
}

cmd1="find_fun | /bin/pax -dwx ustar"
cmd2="/bin/gzip -c"

eval "$cmd1 | $cmd2 > $backfile.tar.gz " 2>/dev/null

echo -e " find ${PIPESTATUS[0]} \npax ${PIPESTATUS[1]} \ncompress ${PIPESTATUS[2]} > $cmdfile
```

Comment: What about it isn't working in the script? Are you executing the script with `bash` or `/bin/sh`?

Comment: i am executing that script in bash.

Comment: Can you show us the **exact** code from your script? Don't remove anything. Don't remove any lines from this section of code. If you need to change filenames/etc. please do so as minimally as possible.

Comment: here is code:
#!/bin/bash
cmdfile=/var/tmp/cmd$$
backfile=/var/tmp/backup$$
find_fun()
{
find /home
}
cmd1="find_fun | /bin/pax -dwx ustar"
cmd2="/bin/gzip -c"
eval "$cmd1 | $cmd2 > $backfile.tar.gz " 2>/dev/null
echo -e " find ${PIPESTATUS[0]} \npax ${PIPESTATUS[1]} \ncompress ${PIPESTATUS[2]} > $cmdfile

Comment: Update the post please so you can format the code correctly.

Comment: But your problem is likely that `eval` only has one return code. If you need all of them you can rewrite to do this without `eval` (which is likely a good idea anyway) or rewrite to echo `PIPESTATUS` from the `eval`ed command and capture that output.

Comment: Thank you for your help Etan Reisner

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are having with your script is that you **aren't** running the same code as you ran on the command line. You are running *different* code. Namely the script has the addition of `eval`. If you were to wrap your command line test in `eval` you would see that it fails in a similar manner.

The reason the `eval` version fails (only gives you one value in `PIPESTATUS`) is because you aren't executing a pipeline anymore. You are executing `eval` on a string that contains a pipeline. This is similar to executing `/bin/bash -c 'some | pipe | line'`. The thing actually being run by the current shell is a single command so it has a single exit code.

You have two choices here:

1. Get rid of `eval` (which you should do anyway as `eval` is generally something to avoid) and stop using a string for a command (see [Bash FAQ 050](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050) for more on why doing this is a bad idea.
2. Move the `echo "${PIPESTATUS[@]}"` into the `eval` and then capture (and split/parse) the resulting output. (This is clearly a worse solution in just about every way.)

Answer (score -1):

Instead of ${PIPESTATUS[0]} use ${PIPESTATUS[@]}

As with any array in bash PIPESTATUS[0] contains the first command exit status. If you want to get all of them you have to use PIPESTATUS[@] which returns all the contents of the array.

I'm not sure why it worked for you when you tried it in the command line. I tested it and I didn't get the same result as you.

Comment: I am sorry about my ignorance. its not ${PIPESTATUS[0]} but ${PIPESTATUS[*]} that i am using. But problem still exist.${PIPESTATUS[@]} is not working for me. I actually want to store those exit status in a file.
echo -e " find    ${PIPESTATUS[0]} \npax   ${PIPESTATUS[1]}   \ncompress   ${PIPESTATUS[2]} > cmdfile.
output i am getting in file is: 
find   0
pax
compress.